# Jenkins scp succeed but no file on destination

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, scp

Using Jenkins, I try to copy builded artefacts with scp to another server.
Jenkins announced success and the right files quantity.

But on remote server there's no traces of any of these files.

How can I log more than scp connection on remote ?

Did you meet this problem before and solved it ?

Thanks for your help, JM

Comment: you can use this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for answering. This is exactly the plugin I used.

Comment: I just found a clue. It seems that my target directories are recreated INSIDE target root directory (/root) !
For example, I want Publish-over-SSH to publish files in /opt/toto, the result is that /root/opt/toto is created and files are published inside !!!